# Counting the number of integers $1 < i < p\#$ where gpf($i$) > $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primorial

- lpf = [least prime factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html)
- gpf = [greatest prime factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestPrimeFactor.html)
- $p\#$ = the [primorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html) of the prime $p$

It is straight forward to count the number of integers $i$ where $1 < i < p\#$ and lpf($i$) $> p$.

If $p$ is the $n$th prime, then the count is $(p_n - 1)*(p_{n-1} - 1) * \dots *(2-1) - 1$

To count the number of integers $i$ where $1 < i < p\#$ and gpf($i$) $ > p$, the only thing that I could come up with is:

1. Count the number where lpf($i$)$ > p$
2. For each of these where lpf($i$)$ > p$ and $i \le \frac{p\#}{2}$, count the number of times each $i$ divides $p\#$ making sure not to double count.
3. Then, add step #2 to $\frac{\text{step #1}}{2}$

Is there a more straight forward way?